# ngbTimepicker not working in ngbmodal with reactive form

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I got an error (**There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "NgbTimepicker"**) when trying to use **NgbTimepicker** in a reactive form in a modal.

In **app.module.ts**, I import **ngbModule**:

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
  ...
],
imports: [
   ...
   NgbModule.forRoot(),
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

In the **page.component.ts**,

```
import { NgbModal, NgbTimepicker} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

...

 workingStartTime: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
```

In the **page.component.html**

```
 <input type="text" formControlName="workingStartTime" placeholder=""
        NgbTimepicker #timepicker="NgbTimepicker (click)="timepicker.toggle()">
```

I spent some hours without success looking what is wrong. Am i doing something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are doing in wrong way, from [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples) also mentioned to use like:

```
<ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="time" formControlName="time"></ngb-timepicker>
```

I have posted a sample in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4nk72n?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Hope this works, Check and let me know if you need more in this.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not correct, it is not how reactive form works. ngModel is used in template forms - not what the OP asked.
To set the value in reactive form you do as you did in html. In the code:

```
this.form.controls.time.setValue({
  "hour": 15,
  "minute":30
});
```

If you have several time pickers in your application you can write timepicker adatapter as shown here: 
[Custom time adapter](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples#adapter)